# Tracking totalBytesSent blocks animations for a few seconds

Tags: swift, upload, progress

I'm currently working on an upload functionality in a Swift iPhone app.

During the upload, I want to show a progress indicator. However, any code command needing the display to be refreshed does not seem to be executed before a few seconds.

For instance with the code below, PROGRESS would appear in the console right away when data would start to be sent out but the top view would disappear only after about 10 seconds.

```
    func URLSession(_ session: NSURLSession,
                  task task: NSURLSessionTask,
                       didSendBodyData bytesSent: Int64,
                                       totalBytesSent totalBytesSent: Int64,
                                                      totalBytesExpectedToSend totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64) {
    //uploadProgressCallback(uploadProgressRatio: min(Double(totalBytesSent) / self.uploadedFileTotalSize, 1.0) )

    print("PROGRESS")
    let topController:UINavigationController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    topController.view.alpha = 0.0


}
```

Any idea why?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Raphaël

Answer (score 0):

Update UI only from main thread to have efficient performance:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in
    //update UI hear
}
```

Comment: Or, create custom `NSURLSession` which calls delegate methods on main queue: `let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(), delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())`